# TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

So I have the following constructor function:

```
function Source(){
    this.health_small = new Image();
    this.health_medium = new Image();
    this.health_large = new Image();
    this.health_mega = new Image();
    this.health_ultra = new Image();
    this.health_small.src = "img/health_small.png";
    this.health_medium.src = "img/health_medium.png";
    this.health_large.src = "img/health_large.png";
    this.health_mega.src = "img/health_mega.png";
    this.health_ultra.src = "img/health_ultra.png";
    this.bullet = new Image();
    this.bullet.src = "img/bullet.png";
    this.pistol_small = new Image();
    this.pistol_medium = new Image();
    this.pistol_large = new Image();
    this.pistol_small.src = "img/pistol_small.png";
    this.pistol_medium.src = "img/pistol_medium.png";
    this.pistol_large.src = "img/pistol_large.png";
    this.heavy_small = new Image();
    this.heavy_medium = new Image();
    this.heavy_large = new Image();
    this.heavy_small.src = "img/heavy_small.png";
    this.heavy_medium.src = "img/heavy_medium.png";
    this.heavy_large.src = "img/heavy_large.png";
    this.shotgun_small = new Image();
    this.shotgun_medium = new Image();
    this.shotgun_large = new Image();
    this.shotgun_small.src = "img/shotgun_small.png";
    this.shotgun_medium.src = "img/shotgun_medium.png";
    this.shotgun_large.src = "img/shotgun_large.png";
}
```

This function has all the images loaded in a object called `src`

I have another ammo constructor function for all ammo, but there is a switch statement to tell what kind of ammo it should be, ex "pistol_ammo".

```
switch(type){
    default: 
    // Small ammo
    case "pistol_small":
    this.width = _9mm_casew;
    this.height = _9mm_caseh; 
    this.giveAmount = amount_small; 
    this.color = color_pistol;
    this.img = src.pistol_small; break;
    case "heavy_small":
    this.width = _heavy_casew;
    this.height = _heavy_caseh; 
    this.giveAmount = amount_small; 
    this.color = color_heavy;
    this.img = src.heavy_small; break;
    case "shotgun_small":
    this.width = _12gauge_casew;
    this.height = _12gauge_caseh; 
    this.giveAmount = amount_small; 
    this.color = color_shotgun;
    this.img = src.shotgun_small; break;
    // Medium ammo
    case "pistol_medium":
    this.width = _9mm_cartw;
    this.height = _9mm_caseh;
    this.giveAmount = amount_medium; 
    this.color = color_pistol;
    this.src = src.pistol_medium; break;
    case "heavy_medium":
    this.width = _heavy_cartw;
    this.height = _heavy_carth;
    this.giveAmount = amount_medium; 
    this.color = color_heavy;
    this.img = src.heavy_medium; break;
    case "shotgun_medium":
    this.width = _12gauge_cartw;
    this.height = _12gauge_carth;
    this.giveAmount = amount_medium; 
    this.color = color_shotgun;
    this.img = src.shotgun_medium; break;
    //Large ammo
    case "pistol_large":
    this.width = _9mm_boxw;
    this.height = _9mm_carth;
    this.giveAmount = amount_large; 
    this.color = color_pistol;
    this.img = src.pistol_large; break;
    case "heavy_large":
    this.width = _heavy_boxw;
    this.height = _heavy_boxh;
    this.giveAmount = amount_large; 
    this.color = color_heavy;
    this.img = src.heavy_large; break;
    case "shotgun_large":
    this.width = _12gauge_boxw;
    this.height = _12gauge_boxh;
    this.giveAmount = amount_large;
    this.color = color_shotgun;
    this.img = src.shotgun_large; break;
}
```

Then finally, if any ammo objects exist on an array, it calls a show function to display it on the canvas.

```
    for(var i = ammo.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        ammo[i].show();
    }
```

This is the show function:

```
this.show = function(){
    g.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y);
}
```

I have searched around on stackoverflow and several other sites

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'
```

I am trying to this all without any libraries or framework.

EDIT: I made some edits due to typos and missing info, sorry :S

Comment: Well the error tells you what is wrong, you didn't pass any of those types of object to the `drawImage()` function. How about you show the code where you actually call `drawImage()` and check to make sure you are actually passing the correct object

Comment: `this.show = function(){
  g.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y);
 }` This function is within the ammo constructor function

Comment: Did you give it enough time to actually download the pictures? This is the worst possible way you can do item management

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did, (I don't usually do images with canvas) but what happens is it shows all the images properly but the error still shows up. Is there a way to show a screen shot or is there a different method that works better?

Comment: **sidenote:** I'm pretty sure `default` should be the last case (or maybe it'll work too when you put a `break` in it)

Comment: I feel like we're missing the code that would allow us to properly determine the flow of your program and what's wrong with it..

Comment: @myfunkyside I tried moving to the end and removing it completely and it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Oh no that's not gonna fix your problem, no that's just a sidenote, something I noticed unrelated to the main problem (talking about my default comment right?)

Comment: My second comment *was* regarding the main problem: I don't think we can fix this without you giving us more code/info..

Comment: This is a large project, there is basically 2 main functions, and the rest are just functions to maintain actions of the script. There is a `window.onload = function(){ /* code here*/ }` and a main function that is run using `setInterval(main, 1000/60);` I am making this project and hosting it on a website, if that is any use.